# how to put @error class on laravelcollective

Tags: laravel

i just install laravelcollective 5.8 and try to put error class on input form like this

```
{{Form::number('nik', '', ['id'=>'nik','min'=>'1','max'=>'999999','class'=>'form-control @error('nik') is-invalid @enderror','placeholder'=>'E.g: 1234','required'])}}
```

first i got error

```
syntax error, unexpected 'nik' (T_STRING), expecting ']'
```

and i try to change @error('nik') to @error("nik") , but no luck, this what happen on inspect element

```
<input id="nik" min="1" max="999999" class="form-control <?php if ($errors->has(&quot;nik&quot;)) :
if (isset($message)) { $messageCache = $message; }
$message = $errors->first(&quot;nik&quot;); ?> is-invalid <?php unset($message);
if (isset($messageCache)) { $message = $messageCache; }
endif; ?>" placeholder="E.g: 1234" required="" name="nik" type="number" value="">
```

this how should be on native laravel blade

```
<input required min="1" max="999999" id="nik" class="form-control @error('nik') is-invalid @enderror" type="number" name="nik" placeholder="E.g: 1234">
```

and inspect element will be :

```
<input required="" min="1" max="999999" id="nik" class="form-control " type="number" name="nik" placeholder="E.g: 1234">
```

anyone know how to solve this, i'll so greatfull..
thank you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything within the `{{ }}` is PHP, not Blade, so a directive like `@error` won't work in there.

```
{{ Form::number('nik', '', [
    'id'=>'nik',
    'min'=>'1',
    'max'=>'999999',
    'class'=>'form-control @error('nik') is-invalid @enderror',
    'placeholder'=>'E.g: 1234',
    'required'
]) }}
```

Instead, do it the PHP way:

```
'class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('nik') ? ' is-invalid' : null),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a helper function and make use of the shared `errors` variable in the view.

```
function add_error($name, $error_class = ' is-invalid ')
{
    $errors = view()->shared('errors');

    return $errors && $errors->has($name) ? $error_class : '';
}
```

And append that to the class.

```
{{ Form::text('name', null, [
    'id'=>'name',
    'class'=>'form-control' . add_error('name'),
    'placeholder'=>'Name',
    'required'
]) }}
```